# how can webflux handle global error, like 404 page not found

Tags: spring-webflux

I use `@Restcontrolleradvice` and `@ExceptionHandler`, I can handle controller exceptions. But I can't handle server errors like 404, and 500.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class HttpExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String exceptions(Exception e) {
        String code = Global.ERR_UNKNOWN;
        if (e instanceof MethodNotAllowedException) {
            code = Global.ERR_HTTP_METHOD;
        }
        return code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Spring Boot, this is already done for you and you can customize this support as well quite easily (see [Spring Boot reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.reactive.webflux.error-handling)).

If you're using plain Spring Framework, then you need to register a custom `WebExceptionHandler` bean to handle that (see [Spring Framework reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-exception-handler)). Because those errors can happen at any point during request handling (i.e. not only during the controller handling phase, but also during response encoding, within a `WebFilter`...), the API there is quite low level and you need to deal with raw `DataBuffer` instances. If you're looking for inspiration on how to achieve higher level error handling support, you can also take a look [at what's done in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/76a450d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java).